# File retrieval using rmi

Tags: java, file-io, rmi

Please tell me how to retrive a file from remote computer to your computer using Remote method Invocation.I shoud be able to give the file path on my computer and retrive the file from the specified path from the remote computer. please help

Comment: RMI is a very poor choice for this purpose, as it requires loading the entire file into memory at both ends. Why do you think you need to use RMI?

Comment: tell me another way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

RMI (remote method invocation) is not for connecting to other computers. It is for connecting to other java applications (that obviously can run either on local or remote machine).

So, you can create 2 applications: client that calls server via RMI. Server will receive client's call, read file from its local file system and transfer it to client.

But IMHO RMI is not the best choice for this task. Probably better solution is to connect to remote machine using one of the protocols it supports natively and retrieve file.

For example is both machines are running windows you can just open file using path liek this `\\remote-host\c$\dir1\dir2\file.txt`.

If remote machine is running Unix you can connect to it using SSH. Use pure java implementation of SSH protocol e.g. [Jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), so the client OS does not matter. If server side is windows and client side is not you can either install SSH server on windows and then user Jsch or use Samba on client machine.

In all cases you can use FTP but it may require to perform some additional configurations. There are several pure java libraries that implement FTP, for example [VFS](http://commons.apache.org/vfs/).

Answer (score 0):

RMI is just a technology. One way to do it would be to run a prossess on the server machine that publishes to RMI, but it doesn't seem to be too secure...

Would it be possible for you to publish these files with FTP or SFTP? At lest it would be a standard way of exchanging files. Also you could run a simple HTTP server that puplishes files in a directory.

One of the issues with implementing this service yourself is that you'd have to be careful when accepting requests, you would need to sanitize path to file. This is error prone and there will be high chance of someone hacking it.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing exactly? You can read the file into a byte array, then give it as a return value of the remote method. But there are other (easier) ways to do it depending on the circumstances.

Comment: Yes that's exactly wat i am doing. I have created a textfield on clientside in which i am giving the path of the file to be retrieved and a retrieve button. On the click event of retrieve button i am calling the retrieve function which i have created on serverside and it is returning byte array. this byte array i am copying in the file on client side through fileoutputstream! I'll send you my code.

Comment: But the function is not getting called on the client side